# How to send data from viewcontroller to embded viewcontroller in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I have one viewcontroller where i am using container view and embedding another viewcontroller in that (using storyboard). I am trying pass data from viewcontroller to embedded viewcontroller using prepersegue but not able to do that.

is there any better way to pass data from viewcontroller to embedded viewcontroller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewMyDiary: UIViewController {

    var alerts = [blogDataModel]() //getting value here from another viewcontroller 


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "calenderSegue", sender: self);

    }

     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "calenderSegue")
        {
            let vc: CalenderViewController = segue.destination as! CalenderViewController
            vc.alerts = alerts
        }
    }
}
```

for this i am getting error like "There are unexpected subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed segue has already fired once or a subview was added programmatically?"

[image]

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this for embed segue..embed segue fired automatically once or a subview was added programmatically

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "calenderSegue", sender: self);

    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

     if let vc: CalenderViewController = segue.destination as? CalenderViewController {
          vc.alerts = alerts
      }

 }
```

remove this code and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for help. But somehow my prepareForSegue is not getting called, can you please help with this..if i am doing anything wrong?

Comment: you are using container view ?

Comment: yes..i am using container view and embedding calenderviewcontroller to that

Comment: add a breakPoint in this method ... before `if (segue.identifier == "calenderSegue")`

Comment: yes..i tried this..but prepareForSegue method is not getting trigger

Comment: Thanks for great help.. its getting trigger and my issue also resolved

Comment: may i know the logic behind this?

Comment: you was not using delegate method .. i think so